# How to edit datesec array in edgar_v5_2015 emission files (netcdf format)?

Tags: wrf-chem, emissions

I am using EDGAR V5 2015 emission files (edgar_v5_2015__0.1x0.1.nc) for WRF-Chem simulation. After giving the **ncdump -v date,datesec edgar_v5_2015_CO_0.1x0.1.nc > ncdump.log** command, I learned that the date and datesec variables of the emission file are-
data:

date = 20150101, 20150201, 20150301, 20150401, 20150501, 20150601, 20150701,
20150801, 20150901, 20151001, 20151101, 20151201 ;

datesec = 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ;
}
Now I want to change the last date in the **'date'** array from **'20151201'** to **'20151231'**. Can anyone please suggest how to do that? Is there any software available for that? I searched online and found a link to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59729526/how-to-edit-global-attributes-in-netcdf-file-with-nco, but there it was discussed how to edit global attributes in a netcdf file with NCO and the problem was different from mine. I have never used NCO, and I am having difficulties understanding what command I should use for this. Can anyone guide me in this regard? That will be very helpful for me. Thank you.

With regards,

Ankan

Comment: I think NCO is the way to go for your problem: Try http://research.jisao.washington.edu/data_sets/nco/ and also: https://nicojourdain.github.io/students_dir/students_netcdf_nco/

Comment: Thank you @arkaia for your response. I will check it out. Thank you again.